# Extraer los primeros 5 dígitos de una columna

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo este DF en python:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me gustaría crear una columna que contenga solo los primeros 5 dígitos. ¿Alguna idea como podría hacerlo?

Lo intenté de esta manera:

```
cuenta1= DF['cuenta'].str[:5]
```

pero me da este error:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!. Did you mean: 'std'?
```

Lo que quisiera es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El error se debe a que tu columna no es de tipo string (seguramente sea de tipo int64). Debes convertir la columna a string antes de poder usar métodos de cadenas vectorizados, en este caso el slicing:

```
DF["cuenta1"] = DF['cuenta'].astype("string").str[:5]
```

y  si quieres que tu columna final siga siendo de tipo `int`:

```
DF["cuenta1"] = DF['cuenta'].astype("string").str[:5].astype("int64")
```